# JavaScript Bridging - Alternative to window.webkit.messageHandlers.handlerNameHere.postMessage()

Tags: ios, objective-c

I've been looking for an alternative for the following:

`window.webkit.messageHandlers.handlerNameHere.postMessage()`

Been searching the web for 2 days now. But, the code above is one of the only two solutions or ways that I've found in several articles and stackoverflow answers.

The other one is the delegate function for UIWebView which is also not the answer I am looking for. Although, I honestly don't want to use a UIWebView since it's already deprecated.

Thank you!